# Missing or broken CSS in main CV chat room

Tags: bug, design

The CSS for the [main CV chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18/ten-fold) is broken/not resolving rendering the room difficult to use. This has been the case for the past few hours and I did try this in clean browser sessions / multiple browsers.

Currently the chat room looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Apologies fir the duplicate: I got an error when submitting the first time, which I corrected and then resubmitted the question. Seems the first one went through anyway.

Comment: As of right now, Ten fold renders fine for me on firefox.

Comment: Firefox failing for me though. It is failing on http://cdn-chat.sstatic.net/chat/css/chat.stats.stackexchange.com.css?v=6744ac13df20 and when I go there I see a page with the [se] logo and the message "We are currently offline for maintenance"

Comment: Yeah, that's giving me a wall of text right now. It starts w/ "body{background:#faf9f6 url(../img/stats-chat-bg.png) repeat;}#input- ...", if that helps. But Ten fold comes through fine.

Comment: That's suggest it should deliver. Odd....

Comment: This appears to have been a temporary issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to have been a temporary issue with the content delivery network CSS file affecting at least one user.